# Laravel5 Eloquent custom method return array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a static method in my `User` model which counts something, i am using a raw statement:

```
static function countOrders($userId)
{
   $sql = "SOME CUSTOM-COMPLICATED QUERY";
   $result = \DB::select( \DB::raw( $sql ) );
   return $result; // <-- toArray() ? returns Exception!
}
```

Somewhere in my controller:

```
$orders = User::countOrders(*USER-ID*);
```

How can I get an array with records as arrays and not objects without modifying the global configuration for the FETCH method?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to run toArray().

When executing raw queries select returns array, it's stated in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/master/database#running-queries):

> The select method will always return an array of results.

```
static function countOrders($userId)
{
   $sql = "SOME CUSTOM-COMPLICATED QUERY";
   $result = \DB::select( \DB::raw( $sql ) );
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'm getting a `Call to a member function get() on a non-object`

Comment: Well I noticed tha you have another error, you must do `\DB::table(''name_of_table")->select(\DB::raw( $sql ))->get()`;

Comment: can you show us your "SOME CUSTOM-COMPLICATED QUERY"

Comment: I've edited my answer, your code was right, you  don't need to do a toArray(), since select already returns an array. Sorry as I have misunderstood your problem

Comment: It returns an array, but each entry in that array is a stdObject, that's my issue. I want each entry to be an array as well.

Comment: You have two options create a function that parses the std object into an array or you can just `$json = json_encode(stdObject)` then decode it again  `$newArray = json_decode($json, true)`